# SharePoint Online CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am running a very simple script to delete all the files in a document library in SharePoint Online. However, the script only runs for a few hundred items and then I have reexecute the script multiple times. The document library has 1000 files. First time, it ran for 400 files. Then, when re-executed, it ran for 200 files. Subsequent runs are 100 files.

My question is that is there a limitation in SharePoint Online that prevents me from recycling all those 1000 files at one go?

Here is my script:
    Here is my script:

```
#Credentials and context retrieve here which works fine so I have omitted it for brevity

$web = $context.Web
$context.Load($web) 
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents")
$context.load($list)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$files = $list.RootFolder.Files
$context.load($files)
$context.ExecuteQuery()


for($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
write-host $files[$i].Name
$files[$i].Recycle()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: do you have multiple folders in your library? also, check the value of $files.Count

Comment: Log the exception from the catch block. You can get additional information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are no folders in the library (other than the root folder of course). I did check the item count and it gives the full count of all the items in the library - but only deletes a few. Interesting thing is when it got to 20 items, it started to only delete about 2-3 items (although item count was correct)

Comment: Thanks Venkat. There is no exception. It runs fine.

Comment: There are alternate ways to delete items in batch from UI or from Coding if you want to try

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to update your code as below?

```
for($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    write-host $files[$i].Name;
    $files[$i].Recycle();
}

$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Fyi. Another way to delete 1000 items at a time from UI

1. Go to site settings.
2. Click "Content and Structure" under "Site Administration".
3. Select your library from the left menu. It will display 1000 items.
4. Select all items and delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the CAML query with row limit(assuming that you know the number of items) to delete items as below:

```
$query=New-ObjectMicrosoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery  
$query.ViewXml="<View><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>"  
$items=$list.GetItems($query)  
$context.Load($items)      
$context.ExecuteQuery()

if ($items.Count -gt 0)  
{  
    for ($i=$items.Count-1; $i -ge 0; $i--)  
    {  
        $items[$i].Recycle()  
    }   
    $context.ExecuteQuery()  
}
```

Or you can use a  `do-while` loop and use the `ListItemCollectionPosition` as below to delete files:

```
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$query.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>"

do
{
    $listItems = $list.getItems($query)
    $context.Load($listItems)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition

    Try
    {
        for ($i=$listItems.Count-1; $i -ge 0; $i--)  
        {  
            $listItems[$i].Recycle()  
        }   
        $context.ExecuteQuery() 
    }
    Catch [System.Exception]
    {
        # This shouldn't happen, but just in case
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    }

}
While($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```